# How to modify default SOAP request?

Tags: c#, asmx

So I'm building a WS using C# ASMX projects. I've already finished it but someone is asking me to change a value on the request. The value that needs to be changed is the body request where it says "request" they need it to say "data" is there any data annotation that does that? Here's the request:

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:request(this is the word to replace)>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Param1></tem:Param1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Param2></tem:Param2>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Param3></tem:Param3>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Param4></tem:Param4>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Param5></tem:Param5>
         </tem:request(this is the word to replace)>
      </tem:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

UPDATE:
The WebMethod looks like this:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public GetDataResponse GetData(GetDataRequest request)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

And GetDataRequest looks like:

```cs
public class GetDataRequest
{
    public string Param1 = String.Empty;
    public string Param2 = String.Empty;
    public string Param3 = String.Empty;
    public string Param4 = String.Empty;
    public string Param5 = String.Empty;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you create the request in the first place?

Comment: I edited my question, added what you asked.

Comment: Rename your `GetDataRequest request` to `GetDataRequest data`?

Comment: @GSerg variable names aren't metadata that is available to reflection (easily), and thus not used. The `request` name has to come from somewhere else.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen This is an ASMX web service. It provides these names in its WSDL, and expects them in requests.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking for an answer, I got to the annotarion: `[XmlRoot("data")]`.
This comes before the class declaration like this:

```
[XmlRoot("data")]
public class GetDataRequest
{
    public string Param1 = String.Empty;
    public string Param2 = String.Empty;
    public string Param3 = String.Empty;
    public string Param4 = String.Empty;
    public string Param5 = String.Empty;
}
```

With this you can change the name that appears at in the request.